# Finding part of a sequence of numerical values in files with unknown name

Tags: extract

I have the following problem I would like to solve.

I have a main table file that contains two columns: a unique identifier and a sequence of numerical values. The file looks [something like this](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqRdIqgiUJYLgvBdWKREI1G0vFHVzw?e=E0iYxd). The numerical values were copied into this file from a number of different Excel or .csv files (not more than 10). Each of these source files contain a part of the numerical values in the main file. These files look [something like this](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqRdIqgiUJYLgvBc7QwdPdwoV0IE2g?e=NnU1L7).

I know the approximate, although not the exact length of each of the sub-sequences making up the numerical values in the column in the main file. I do not know the name of the .csv or Excel file where they originally came from.

I would like to do three things:

1. For each part of the values in the main file, determine which source file they originally came from.
2. Identify all numerical values that are in the same column but above and below this sub-sequence in the source file.
3. Copy these numerical values from the column of the sub-sequence in the source file into a new column in the main file.
4. Save. The results should [look like this](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqRdIqgiUJYLgvBeECOfA28iwJ824Q?e=G3Azwv).

To restate this, the problems are:

1. I do not know the exact length of each sub-sequence, although I know the approximate length.
2. I do not know the source file for each sub-sequence of the numerical values in the main file.

In principle, this could be done by hand, but I would rather not. Does someone have an idea how to approach this?

Comment: The given link cannot be accessed. Please update/check the link. ( :